# Can I trigger a jenkins dsl pipelineJob from another job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl, jenkins-dsl

I have a jenkins DSL freestyleJob which polls a github repo and triggers when it detects a change.

I want to trigger a 'pipeline' job within this freestyleJob. Is this possible?

I see in the web ui that I can add a 'post-build' step to build another project, and specify my pipeline. How would I actually code this in my jenkins casc job?

I tried the following:

```bash
    freeStyleJob('poll_scm_job') {
        scm {
            github('my-repo/test-jenkins', '*/main')
        }
        triggers {
            scm('H/2 * * * *')
        }
        steps {
            shell(readFileFromWorkspace('jobs/Myjob.groovy'))
        }
        postBuildSteps('SUCCESS') {
            shell("echo 'post build step'")
        }
    }
```

However this caused the job-configurator to fail with error:
ERROR: (script, line 19) No signature of method: javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.jobs.FreeStyleJob.postBuildSteps() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, script$_run_closure1$_closure7) values: [SUCCESS, script$_run_closure1$_closure7@6f249809]

I also tried the following with a similar error:

```bash
    freeStyleJob('poll_scm_job') {
        scm {
            github('my-repo/test-jenkins', '*/main')
        }
        triggers {
            scm('H/2 * * * *')
        }
        steps {
            shell(readFileFromWorkspace('jobs/Myjob.groovy'))
            build(job: 'PostBuildJob')
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I figured it out, atleast on my set up the following created the post-build step which called my pipeline successfully

```
freeStyleJob('poll_scm_job') {
        scm {
            github('my-repo/test-jenkins', '*/main')
        }
        triggers {
            scm('H/2 * * * *')
        }
        steps {
            shell(readFileFromWorkspace('scripts/test/myjob.sh'))
        }
        publishers {
            downstream('my-pipeline', 'SUCCESS')
        }
}
```